# Hamburger menu desktop

Tags: responsive-design, web, hamburger-menu

I have a really simple question: in what occassion should I use the hamburger menu on desktop websites. Or is there no situation that this is usefull? I am really curious about your opions about that!

Answer (score 0):

(Design perspective) No situation. With a desktop application you should have ample space to provide some type of visually appealing menu that can accordion or swipe off, spin and disappear the possibilities are endless. However, for mobile this is an icon that is easily understood and takes up little space. A user automatically knows AH there is the menu. For a generic menu not just the button Apple is notorious for providing a long list of things to swipe on.